# Why my function make Ghrome Chrome stop working ?(JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, string

I've been training on the CodeWars site and I should have done following exercise:

**"Complete the solution so that it splits the string into pairs of two characters. If the string contains an odd number of characters then it should replace the missing second character of the final pair with an underscore ('_')."**

BUT my problem is that I've got nothing from the output on the site and when I tried to test my function in Google Chrome console it's just don't return or print anything and the whole browser just stop working...What did I do wrong? There are no "infinite" conditions... What may cause the problem?

[Screenshot of output from the CodeWars](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wzxo4.jpg)

```js
function solution(str){

  var result = [];
  
   if((str.length % 2) === 0) {
     for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i + 2){
       result.push(str.substr(i, 2));
     }
   } else {
   
     for (var i = 0; i < (str.length); i + 2){
       result.push(str.substr(i, 2));
     }
     
     result.push(str.substr(str.length - 1, 1) + '_');
     
     };
     
     return result;
};
```

Comment: You do have an infinite cycle because you are not incrementing `i`, `i + 2` should be `i = i + 2` or `i += 2`

Answer (score 0):

Your for loops are wrong. They do not increment `i`. Use `i += 2`.

`for (let i = 0; i < (str.length); i += 2)`